# Angular: Show response from multiple requests as they load

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an Angular HTTP service that fetches the desired data from the backend. This particular call is fired multiple times to get data of different IDs.

```
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

getDataById(id) {
  return this.http.get(URL + id)
    .pipe(delay(getRandomMillis(500, 10000));
}
```

I have added an Rx delay to simulate random network delay.
This is then used in my component as:

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  response: any[];
  idsToQuery = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8];

  ngOnInit() {
    const requests = this.idsToQuery.map(i => this.myService.getDataById(i));
    forkJoin(requests).subscribe(res => {
      this.response = res;
    });
  }
}
```

This works for most of the part except that the `response` is shown only when the longest time consuming call finishes. I want to show the response as soon as it arrives, without worrying about the order. I tried `zip` and `combineLatest` to no avail.

Comment: Try merge (not mergeMap)

Comment: Thanks! That works, however it adds an inner Observable that I have to subscribe again to show the data

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can directly subscribe to each request which in turn pushes the data as soon as it loads:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.idsToQuery.map(i => this.myService.getDataById(i).subscribe(res => {
        this.response.push(res);
    }));
}
```